# How to get the ALL the dates of the current week?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

Is there a way to get all the dates of the current week?
For example today is 11/22/2021.
So I need an array of
`["11/21/2021", "11/22/20201", "11/23/2021", "11/24/2021", "11/25/2021", "11/26/2021", "11/27/2021"]`

Also this array needs to be consistent for the entire week until it is Sunday, then it will create a new array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Days b/w current week in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871998/how-to-get-the-days-b-w-current-week-in-moment-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS- Get days of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008354/js-get-days-of-the-week)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
Array.from(Array(7).keys()).map((idx) => {const d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() - d.getDay() + idx); return d; });
```

Some explanation, `Array(7)` will create an empty array with 7 entries.

`Array(7).keys()` will return an iterator with the array keys.

`Array.from(Array(7).keys())` will transform the iterator into a new array with 7 entries containing integers (aka `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`)

`d.getDate() - d.getDay() + idx`, we take the current day (23), remove the day of week (0 for Sunday, 2 for Tuesday... Basically we calculate the last Sunday date) et add number of days to have every date in the week.